# How to translate check constraint from SQL Server to Oracle

Tags: oracle, ddl, check-constraints

I'd have to translate the followed sql server constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblLocal_FDIMP_SRCDESCFTP]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [fmtfile_chk] CHECK  (
   (  (1) = case 
            when [file_type]='LBC' AND [fmtfile]='ZIP' then (1) 
            when ([file_type]='AE' OR [file_type]='TS') AND ([fmtfile] IS NULL OR upper([fmtfile])='ZIP') then (1) 
            else (0) end
))GO
```

What would be the equivalent constraint translate to Oracle syntax ?

Thanks

Comment: That's not a SQL Server constraint, that's just ugly code. A simple boolean condition would work just fine. Luis shows that simply *removing* all the `CASE ... WHEN` and comparisons to 1 would leave a simple boolean expression

Comment: I just realized that fmtfile can only be ZIP or NULL. That's nonsense.

Comment: @Stefano . . . I don't see why this wouldn't work in Oracle, although I would not write it this way in any database.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I don't know if the code above works in oracle. But reading on google, regarding at the syntax, it seemed unused to me in Oracle like this (1) = case ecc. I Could to make a mistake but  to check I can perform both syntaxs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do people use `1 = CASE` for conditions?

```
ALTER TABLE tblLocal_FDIMP_SRCDESCFTP 
ADD  CONSTRAINT fmtfile_chk CHECK  ((file_type='LBC' AND fmtfile='ZIP') 
                                OR ((file_type='AE' OR file_type='TS') AND (fmtfile IS NULL OR UPPER(fmtfile)='ZIP')));
```

Comment: *"Why do people use `1 = CASE` for conditions?"* Umm, because it's so much more Computer-Sciency?

Comment: @LuisCazeres . . . It is only necessary in databases that don't support a proper `boolean` type.  Why don't databases support a boolean type?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I've never seen a place where this is necessary. I've only seen it prevent queries from being SARGable.